# While serving notice period, an offer was given and revoked. What now?

Tags: job-offer, india, notice-period, counter-offer

I work in an IT firm in India. I have been serving notice since January 25 to my current organization. Two days ago, they gave me a generous offer and I revoked my notice period based on that. Please note this is the last week of my notice period.

They wanted me to be available for midnight deployments, but I refused. So they revoked my new offer.

April 25 will be the last working day. I asked the project manager about the handover, she said she will let me know.

I am worried about what will happen next?

**Update**

Apologies, for not being clear enough. I am leaving for a new organization. In the resignation acceptance email, HR has written my last working day is April 25.

The notice period is of 90 days, and I  am leaving after completing my notice period. I have not declined the offer from the new company.

I had clearly stated that I withdraw my resignation because I have a new offer. When I don't have the offer revoked does my resignation still stands?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135763/discussion-on-question-by-gabrielle-while-serving-notice-period-an-offer-was-gi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to ignore the second company, because it really has nothing to do with this.

The sequence is:

- You resigned
- You worked through most of your notice period
- They approached you with a better contract
- You revoked your resignation to discuss the better contract

Then one of three things happened:

1. You then could not agree with all terms in the contract
2. They revoked the better contract
3. The new contract was agreed upon, but then they fired you

Depending on the wording of correspondence between you and your company, different things could be argued. In any case, in any of the three scenarios, I would simply say that the renegotiation of contract could not be completed, and therefore your original notice period stands.

Comment: You are right about the sequence of events. They haven't been responding, that is why I was doubtful about it. Thanks for clearing it.

Comment: Make sure you have your own copy of all correspondence, printed out or stored where your employer cannot erase it.